# Java Swing Widget that Displays Information

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a game and I need some sort of widget that displays text information (specifically, what level the user is on). Does anyone know if the swing library has an existing widget for this?

Comment: Which swing components did you already try, and why are they not working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Swing Components can render text - but in different ways. For rendering some very simple text:

- [JLabel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) - to easily render text that does not need user interaction
- [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) - renders text that the user can interact with

Answer (score 1):

See the Swing tutorial on the [Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/componentlist.html).

The most basic component for this would be a `JLabel`.